# Where is tMap's temporary data stored?

Tags: talend

I would like to know where Talend Open Studio stores temporal data for tMap component if you set **Store temp data** variable to true in a lookup flow, but you dont set the **Temp data directory path** variable explicitly:

[image]

[image]

Also, I would like to know if this temporal data is deleted automatically.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in these [lines of code from tMap](http://talendforge.org/trac/tos/browser/trunk/org.talend.designer.components.localprovider/components/tMap/tMap_begin.inc.javajet?rev=21209#L46):

```
String tempFolder = ElementParameterParser.getValue(node,"__TEMPORARY_DATA_DIRECTORY__");
if (tempFolder.equals("")) {
tempFolder=ElementParameterParser.getValue(node.getProcess(), "__COMP_DEFAULT_FILE_DIR__") + "/temp";                
}
```

so, the default temp dir is inside the workspace. The dir won't be deleted by default, but files inside will (as usual)